# I can start my server but then I can not write any more code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run `rails server`, my Rails application will successfully start, but after this I am not able to type in any more code.

This is what it looks like:

```
Bens-MacBook-Pro:~ BenDouglas$ cd awesome_app
Bens-MacBook-Pro:awesome_app BenDouglas$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2014-02-06 18:05:40] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-02-06 18:05:40] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0]
[2014-02-06 18:05:40] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=45336 port=3000
```

Now I can not type anything because it does not bring up Bens-MacBook any more.

All I want to be able to do is still use the terminal.

Comment: It would be very useful for you to learn how to use your terminal sessions. You're going to spend a lot of time there and need to know how to start and stop applications, suspend them, send them to the background and bring them to the foreground again. These are basic skills for a programmer.

Answer (score 4):

This is normal and expected behavior. The server stays running until you kill it.

You need to open another terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

If your some reason you absolutely had to reuse that terminal you could tell rails to daemonize by running:

```
rails server -d
```

It's a little more tricky to stop but `kill $(lsof -i :3000 -t)` may do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on what was already said here, the command "rails server" (or "rails s" to save keystrokes) starts running a process that is bound to that terminal window. Your Rails application is now being run in a WEBrick process. All the output from that process will feed into that window.

Most commands in the terminal execute quickly and then return a prompt. WEBrick is different and will run until you type "CTRL-C".

Open your browser and go to the URL:

`http://localhost:3000`

That terminal window will fill up with more output from Rails. This is one way you will debug your rails app.